# Difficulty with storing key-value pairs in Binary Search Tree in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I need to store user objects with each key in my BST. class `BSTNode` represents the nodes of our tree.

Here is the code of my BST node class:

```
class BSTNode(): 
    def __init__(self, key, value=None): 
        self.key = key 
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None
```

When I try inputting usernames as keys and user objects as values

```
tree = BSTNode(john.username, john)
```

The following error gets thrown:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [62], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #Level 0
----> 2 tree = BSTNode(john.username, john)

NameError: name 'john' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is john object already created , seems python is not able to identify `john.username`. Also better to store the key as the object itself rather than `john.username` as it will resolve to the username value itself.

Answer (score 0):

It says john is not created. it means error is at last line at which you are making instance of `BSTNode` and passing value of `john.username` and john is not defined previously. so please defined the variable `john` first.